# Show Decimal In SQL Calculation

Tags: t-sql

This is always returning 0000 not any data.  Why is such?

```
CONVERT(SUM(decimal(18,10),a.timeontelephone)/1600))
```

Comment: There's no way that returns anything; that's not valid T-SQL at all.  You've got three left parentheses, and four right parentheses for starters, and your `CONVERT` and `SUM` functions need to be swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(18,10),SUM(a.timeontelephone))/1600
FROM TableName a
```